# nginx reverse proxy multidomain

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

i have some problem with my nginx configuration. I am new with nginx by the way ..

I want to host multiple websites on one single server. Ubuntu 16.04 installed.

Example:
  www.myDomain.com - should point to a normal webroot equ: /var/www/html
  wiki.myDomain.com - should reverse-proxy to my confluence application at localhost:8090
  blog.myDomain.com - should point to another webroot equ: /var/www/blog

I tried to configure the base url = www.myDomain.com and the wiki reverse proxy.

My files look like this:

**default:**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
#       listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name myDomain.com www.myDomain.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {

        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

        server_name myDomain.com www.myDomain.com

        include snippets/ssl-www.myDomain.com.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;



        root /var/www/html;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name myDomain.com www.myDomain.com;



        location / {
allow all;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        location /phpmyadmin {

          root /usr/share/;
          index index.php index.html index.htm;

          location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

          }

          location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
            root /usr/share/;
          }

        }

}
```

**my wiki.myDomain.com witht the reverse proxy:**

```
server {
        listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
        server_name wiki.myDomain.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {


        listen wiki.myDomain.com:443 ssl;
#        listen [::]:443;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";


        include snippets/ssl-wiki.myDomain.com.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

#        root /var/www/wiki.myDomain.com;

        location /.well-known {
                root /var/www/wiki.myDomain.com/;
#               default_type text/plain;
        }


        location / {
                client_max_body_size 100m;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
        }

        location /synchrony {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8091/synchrony;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        }

}
```

**So here my problem:**
Wiki.myDomain.com is working fine !
www.eida.at is allways auto forwarding to https://wiki.myDomain.com for some reason

with www.myDomain.com i want to have a separate website - no forward to the wiki. Seems that the reverse proxy part is used any time - doesnt matter which url i choose.

Thanks for help !

Comment: Use `nginx -T` to test the configuration and see what `nginx` is using. It sounds like only the second configuration file is being used. Also, you have two `server_name` directives in one `server` block and none in another.

Comment: nginx is using /etc/nginx/nginx.conf - in this file all files from the /sites-enabled directory is included. In this file my both config files are included. So it should be ok. I corrected the server name commands accordingly - same result. When i enter www.myDomain.com into the browser - it forwards me allways to wiki.myDomain.com

Comment: I tested now a new instalaltion of nginx with a fresh Ubuntu installation. First i created the default config for www.myDomain.com. This worked without any Problem. Than i configured a simple Virtual Domain with a different web root. The Result is that i can reach the virtual domain with test.myDomain,com but whenever i try to get to www.myDomain.com it redirects me to test.myDomain.com. Is it possible that my problem is somewhere else and not in nginx config ? Maybe the DNS records ? I created the subdomains with A Records to the public IP. Or maybe the hosts file of the server ?

Comment: seems that nginx cannot distinguish between subdomains for some reason ...